# How To Complete All Waves in Pumpkin Moon Event

Tags: terraria

I can get up to wave 10 in the Pumpkin Moon event but I can never get past it. My weapons are:

- Godly Vampire Knives
- Legendary Terra Blade
- Zealous Scourge of the Corruptors
- Paladins Hammer
- Magnet sphere r
- Raven staff

and a few other things that I can't remember.

My armor is full beetle and my accessories are

- wings
- celestial stone
- moon stone
- magic carpet and
- lava waders.

All my accessories are warding and I have 99 defense so if anyone can help me please do.

Comment: Set up traps? Get better weapons/armour/accessories?

Comment: From your gear, it sounds like you're trying as hard as possible to play any other class rather than a Summoner, but you're using Summoner armor. That could be your issue.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Beetle armor is not for summoners. Are you thinking of the Hercules Beetle accessory?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Ah okay, I think so, it's been a long while since I've played and my brain is a little fuzzy on it all.. thanks :)

Comment: just search for it on youtube. there are tons of videos, and tons of strategies. really, though, with that gear it wouldn't take you even a day to get post-moonlord gear and just breeze through to wave 15. it's that easy. if that's not what you want, try the cannon-method. it's what i do in speedruns when i'm lazy and want the pumpkin moon gear right after killing plantera.

Comment: I am not a summoner trust me I am really bad at it so what armour would you recommend cause I am a melee fighter.

Answer (score 2):

Watch HappyDays' video [Here!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QIhDKyQ_kg) I hope it helps!

main points:

- You should make an arena.
- Use spear traps and spiky ball traps shooting down into a small platform with lava around it to manipulate spawns on there.
- Keep moving and make a platform high-ish up in the sky to be safe. Maybe use summoner armor, because you have the raven staff. Or shoot down with terra blade.
- Once pumpkings spawn, fly around and dodge + kill them.

Comment: fixed it ok? :)

Comment: Much better, +1.

Answer (score 1):

For Pumpkin Moon, Frost Moon, and similar events and bosses, I'd suggest building a fighting arena with traps.

The gist of this is a large open area with platforms elevated above a pit. The idea is that you'll be standing/running about on the platform above the pit, and can shoot down on enemies from there. Enemies will spawn off-screen and run towards you, but inevitably end up stuck in the pit, so lining the sides/floor with some sort of trap block connected to a timer is a good idea - this will mean those enemies in the pit will take continuous damage over time. This allows you to concentrate on the harder sub-bosses, like the Pumpking.

There are plenty of online guides with many different arena designs, and there are a lot of things you can add to make them really useful - pits of honey, campfires and heart lanterns for health regeneration, heart or star statues to spawn buffs, all sorts of things.

By all accounts you shouldn't have any trouble with your current gear as it is certainly good enough to beat these events; an arena will make it easier, but in the meantime just keep trying, figure out a strategy for dealing with each type of enemy and avoiding their damage, and keep practising!